# Why am I getting the "argument is of length 0" bug when comparing an array element in an if statement for the 8 queens problem

Tags: r, arrays, n-queens

EDIT: I had some indexing issues and some syntax typos as well, I updated my code accordingly but I'm still getting the same error

I'm trying to solve the 8 queens problem using R but when I run my checkOpen function it returns with the error "argument is of length 0." I'm curious as to why this error is occurring, any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

```
checkOpen <- function(board, row, col){
  for(i in col){
    if(board[row,i,]== 1){
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
  i <- row
  j <- col
  while(i > 0 && j > 0){
    if (board[i,j,] == 1){
      return(FALSE)
    }
    i <- i-1
    j <- j-1
  }
  i <- row
  j <- col
  while(i < row && j > 0){
    if(board[i,j,] == 1){
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

placeQueenRecursive <- function(board, column){
  if(column >= col_global){
    return(TRUE)
  }
  for(i in row_global){
    if(checkOpen(board, i, column)){
      board[i,column,] <- 1
      if(placeQueenRecursive(board, column+1) == True){
        return(TRUE)}
      board[i,column,] <- 0}
      }
}

placeQueen <- function(board,queens){
  if(placeQueenRecursive(board, 0) == False){
    print("No Solution")
    return(FALSE)
  }
  print(board)
  return(TRUE)
}



queens <<- 0
row_global <<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
col_global <<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

empty <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

board <<- array(c(empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty), dim = c(8,8,2))
print(board[1,1,])
print(board)
placeQueen(board,queens)
```

Comment: All these checks against `-1` seem problematic. Note that R uses 1-based indexing for it's data.structures. You should not be looking for values at index 0.

Comment: Do you know what happens if you try to use 0 as an index

Comment: I forgot about the 1-indexing and fixed it thanks! All the checks against -1 are now against 0, so it should look for values at index 1 instead. However, I'm still getting the "argument is of length 0" bug

Comment: When you call `placeQueenRecursive(board, 0)`, look where that 0 is going. If you need a basic introduction to debugging your R code, perhaps try https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html

Comment: First, what you want to do is quite unclear when you say `if(column >= col_global)`, since col_global is a vector. Maybe you want to use `all` ? or `any` ? Furthermore, use `TRUE` and `FALSE` instrad of `True` / `False`; Finaly, in `placeQueen`, i think you should use `placeQuennRecurisive(board,1)` and not `placeQuennRecurisive(board,0)` since 0 is not a column index, which is the issue that produce the error you talked about.